# Unable to get all the id tags and a/href tags inside a div using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the html code:

```
<div class="main_class">
    <a id = "link_id" href = "link1"></a>
    <a id = "link_id" href = "link2"></a>
    <a id = "link_id" href = "link3"></a>
    <a id = "link_id" href = "link4"></a>
</div>
```

All the `id`'s have the same name

I tried using beautiful soup to extract all the `a tags` and `id` under a specific `div`

These are the methods I used:

```
filtered = soup.find_all("div[class=main_class")
filtered = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "link_id"})
filtered = soup.find_all('id', href = True) # Returns extra links which are not in the specific div
```

I have tried some other methods but I am unable to get all the `id` and `links` inside a specific `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
links = soup.find("div", {"class": "main_class"}).findChildren("a", {"id": "link_id"})
```

```
>>> links
[<a href="link1" id="link_id"></a>,
 <a href="link2" id="link_id"></a>,
 <a href="link3" id="link_id"></a>,
 <a href="link4" id="link_id"></a>]
```